# Is it possible to write VSTS dashboards in pure html

Tags: azure-devops

We use VSTS dashboards and like to use "embedded webpage" widget to display customized information. We do this by linking to a server where we put some code that calls the VSTS rest api. We authenticate using Personal Access Tokens stored on the server(PAT)

To simplify this process we could skip the server and PATs altogether by using the embedded webpage widget and point it to a html file. This html file would contain javascript and perform the api calls to VSTS and display the information. This however is not possible because of CORS restrictions. We would need to provide a PAT to perform CORS which complicates things.

One work around for this is to host the html page in git in VSTS. If we do this the CORS policy would match but it is not possible to get the file from git with content type as text/html so the html is not rendered when put in the widget.

I also tried the IFrame extension which allows iframe from data: URI but data URIs seems to have a different origin so it doesn't transfer the cookie which means it wont authenticate.

I understand there is a security risk that it would be possible to perform api calls on behalf on whoever is viewing the dashboard so it may be by design if it is not possible.

Is is possible to make a VSTS widget in pure html that calls VSTS api without using PATs?

Comment: I don't understand clearly, can you provide the sample to explain it?

Comment: I can try to elaborate but it is difficult to provide samples for something that doesn't work. Is there any specific part that is unclear?

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve, seems it is related to credential. If so you can use VSS.getAccessToken() to get current user's access token.

Comment: I'm trying to write it in pure html using the rest apis. I've rewritten the question for clarity

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, you need to do it in extension html file directly.